# Can two actions pass for @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-4, code-first

This is my view.

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink( item.courseCategory,"FilteredCourses",
             new { crsCtgry = item.courseCategory },
             new AjaxOptions{
                  UpdateTargetId = "CourseList", 
                  InsertionMode.Replace,
                  HttpMethod = "GET" } )
```

Once after clicked on this, FilteredCourses action will call and the result will shows inside the CourseList div tag. that part is working.I need to print the value of the clicking link(item.courseCategory) inside the same div location. (ex: if i click a link "Science", I want to print Science in same view and the specific location)How could i do this using the above code segment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal `Html.ActionLink` helper method instead of the `Ajax.ActionLink` method and do the ajax loading of the grid yourself. It is very minimal code and you get the flexibility to do whatever you want.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.courseCategory,"FilteredCourses","YourControllerName",
      , new {  course = item.courseCategory}, 
        new { @class = "myLink",data_courseName=item.courseCategory }


<h2 id="courseSelection" />
<div id="CourseList"></div>
```

This will produce a anchor tag for each item with a html 5 data attribute called "`data-coursename`" which will have the value of the courseCategory.

Now a little javascript to handle the click event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  $("a.myLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

   var _this=$(this);

   $.get(_this.attr("url"),function(res){

     //Update the list
     $("#CourseList").html(res);

     //Update the title/header
     $("#courseSelection").html(_this.data("coursename"));

   });        

  });    

});
</script>
```